# How do I connect to a MySQL database over SSL with Laravel 5.3

Tags: mysql, database, ssl, laravel-5

I've been searching all over the internet and haven't had any success.

eg: https://laravel.io/forum/06-18-2014-connecting-mysql-over-ssl?page=1 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/connecting-to-mysql-via-ssl-from-lumen

I'm trying to connect to an azure mysql database over ssl from my laravel application.

I've confirmed I can connect to the database if I turn ssl off. So the settings are correct. What trips me up, and what I can find no documentation on is how to connect via ssl. I've got a sslkey - which I've confirmed can be used to to connect to the database with one of my database management programs - so the pieces are there.

Laravel, however, seems to be failing.

Here's my database driver:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
            'options'   => array(
                            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => '\ssl\DatabaseCACert.pem'),
        ],
```

What am I missing? The database is just refusing the connection at the moment. `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]` So it's close.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the full path to the files. If they're in your laravel application folder then you can use the `base_path` method to generate the full poth. You may also need to define the cert and ca.

```
'options' => [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => base_path('ssl/client-key.pem'),
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => base_path('ssl/client-cert.pem'),
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => base_path('ssl/ca-cert.pem')
]
```

Comment: The base_path note helps, though it doesn't solve the issue. All of Microsoft's azure documentation specifies only the one .pem file for connecting to azure. But will try generating the others and see if your solution works.

Comment: This is for 2 way SSL(mutual ssl). But it's possible the server is using one way SSL (like Azure)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Solved the issue. Hopped on the phone with microsoft and noticed one of the log errors was:

```
PDO::__construct(): Peer certificate CN=`resourceregion-a.control.database.windows.net' did not match expected CN=`db.mysql.database.azure.com'
```

And that line in the documentation that @alexejenko points out, the bit after that:

" If you require to use "--ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY", then you can ping your server name to resolve the regional server name, such as westeurope1-a.control.database.windows.net, and use that regional server name in the connection until this issue is resolved. We plan to remove this limitation in the future."

Turns out this is what was happening. The database connection was routing to the regional database, not mine. So yay for not quite finished products.

Once I changed my DB_HOST to that region it successfully connected (note: make sure you've whitelisted your ips).

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the same error is displayed when you don't have permissions for access remotely to the database.

example here:

- Server1-app: 123.123.123.12
- Server2-database: 456.456.456.45

So, you can try from Server1-app:

```
$ mysql -u youruser -h yourpassword;
```

And into mysql terminal, check if you are able to access to the database:

```
$ show databases;
```

If your database is shown, you have privileges and everything is ok, if not, you must acces to your Server2-database and grant privileges to your user.

Once in Server2-database;

```
$ mysql -u root -p
$ GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database.* TO 'youruser'@'123.123.123.12';
$ FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
$ exit;
```

Hope it be helpful;