# How to connect to azure mysql database using PDO ssl

Tags: php, mysql, azure, pdo, azure-web-app-service

I am using PDO to connect to Azure Mysql database.
I have got the file i was instructed to download.

```
 array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem.txt',$port

)
```

But i get an error
The Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

I have looked at the connection strings provided by AZURE for PHP and i didnt find one of PDO using SSL_CA like others
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Which PHP version are you using? Try to use the latest one. If you enabled “peer verification”, disable it and try again. Also, try to generate a new SSL Certificate and test an endpoint on the server to ensure that it is working properly. As per this SO thread: [How do I connect to a MySQL database over SSL with Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061170/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-over-ssl-with-laravel-5-3), If you require to use "--ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY", then you can ping your server name to resolve the regional server name, such as westeurope1-a.control.database.windows.net, and use that regional server name in the connection until this issue is resolved. Change the DB_HOST to that region and try it again.

Comment: I have pinged but i get a Request timed out