# Laravel SSL connection to MySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ssl, laravel-5

I'm working on a project where I have to use SSL to connect to the MySQL database. This is working in vanilla PHP, but not when I try to use Laravel.

Working PHP-code:

```
<?php
$host = 'xxx';
$db = 'xxx';
$user = 'xxx';
$pass = 'xxx';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => "../rootCA.pem",
];

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

$data = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM x LIMIT 100')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_export($data);
```

But when I try to connect via Laravel, then i get the following error:

```
C:\*\*\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 330
[Fri Sep 14 11:35:05 2018] ::1:54869 [500]: /data - Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\*\*\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 330
```

My Laravel (5.7) config for the connection:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'xxx'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'xxx'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'xxx'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'xxx'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA  => '../rootCA.pem',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
        ),
    ],
```

Any ideas? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with the connectcion it self. It was that I tried to fetch to many rows from my SQL-query which (really strange) gave me error messages like:

> SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

etc. So my bad - but I was hoping that the error messages could have been better.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide full path of files.

```
'options' => [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => base_path('ssl/client-key.pem'),
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => base_path('ssl/client-cert.pem'),
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => base_path('ssl/ca-cert.pem')
]
```

Please see link: [How do I connect to a MySQL database over SSL with Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061170/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-over-ssl-with-laravel-5-3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did try this as well, unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: Hello @Tibbelit, Please change memory_limit in php.ini. Like

; Old Limit
; memory_limit = 512M

; New Limit
memory_limit = 2048M

Comment: Did try to change it to "-1" as well, didn't help :/
    VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process this command.


VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.


VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process this command.


[Fri Sep 14 13:49:08 2018] ::1:57501 [500]: /data - Out of memory (allocated 838860800) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\Projects\*\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 330