# PDO exception on MariaDB connection, peer certificate doesn't match

Tags: azure-database-mysql

I'm receiving a PDO exception when attempting to connect to an Azure MariaDB database over SSL.

The issue stems from the fact the peer certificate does not match the hostname I am connecting to.

I have researched the issue as much as possible. The following links match my issue:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24210#issuecomment-465256195
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44065629

I can connect if I change the hostname to `cr1.ukwest1-a.control.database.windows.net`, however this is not an acceptable workaround. Disabling SSL is not an option, neither is disabling peer verification.

The Lumen database connection options.

```php
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => storage_path('BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem')
            ]),
        ],
    ],
```

The PDO exception as reported by Lumen.

```
PDO::__construct(): Peer certificate CN=`cr1.ukwest1-a.control.database.windows.net' did not match expected CN=`jay-mariadb-staging.mariadb.database.azure.com'
```

**Edit**

I attempted to manually connect using PDO, rather than relying on Lumens classes. This results in the same error message.

```
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => storage_path('BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem')
);
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=jay-mariadb-staging.mariadb.database.azure.com;port=3306;dbname=azure', username@jay-mariadb-staging', password, $options);
```